# How can I enable shooting only when the npc is in aiming animation?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a Animator. First the npc start walking then he stop slowly and aiming. Then with a script I did that when I click the mouse left button it will shoot. This is the last shooting state in the Animator.
Between the walk state and the aiming state I added a parameter and set it to true in the transition :

[image: Animator]

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Shooting : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private Transform[] firePoints;
    [SerializeField]
    private Rigidbody projectilePrefab;
    [SerializeField]
    private float launchForce = 700f;
    [SerializeField]
    private Animator anim;
    [SerializeField]
    private bool automaticFire = false;
    [SerializeField]
    private bool slowDownEffect = false;

    private void Start()
    {
        anim.SetBool("Shooting", true);
    }

    public void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1") && automaticFire == false)
        {
            if (anim.GetBool("Shooting") == true)
            {
                anim.Play("SHOOTING");
                LaunchProjectile();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (automaticFire == true)
            {
                anim.Play("SHOOTING");
                LaunchProjectile();
            }
        }
    }

    private void LaunchProjectile()
    {
        foreach (var firePoint in firePoints)
        {
            Rigidbody projectileInstance = Instantiate(
                projectilePrefab,
                firePoint.position,
                firePoint.rotation);

            projectileInstance.AddForce(new Vector3(0, 0, 1) * launchForce);

            projectileInstance.gameObject.AddComponent<BulletDestruction>().Init();
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is when I'm running the game if I will click the mouse left button "Fire1" it will jump/change from the walk animation to the shooting animation at once and will start shooting.

I want that first the npc will walk then it will change to aiming when he finished changing to aiming only then to be able to shoot "Fire1" .

If the npc is still walking or in the middle of changing to aiming don't allowed to shoot.
Enabling shooting should be only when the npc is in the aiming animation.

Comment: Well instead of `Play("SHOOTING")` you could do `Play("AIMING")` and have a transition from AIMING to SHOOTING?

Comment: You can add two events to your animation timeline. first one is fired when aiming is enabled, and calls a method and sets a boolean variable, the other one is fired when aiming is disabled and calls another method and resets the same variable.

Comment: I will add my own working solution since it's working very good like I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Shooting : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private Transform[] firePoints;
    [SerializeField]
    private Rigidbody projectilePrefab;
    [SerializeField]
    private float launchForce = 700f;
    [SerializeField]
    private Animator anim;
    [SerializeField]
    private bool automaticFire = false;
    [SerializeField]
    private bool slowDownEffect = false;

    private void Start()
    {
        anim.SetBool("Shooting", true);
    }

    public void Update()
    {
        if (isAnimationStatePlaying(anim, 0, "AIMING") == true)
        {
            if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1") && automaticFire == false)
            {
                if (anim.GetBool("Shooting") == true)
                {
                    anim.Play("SHOOTING");
                    LaunchProjectile();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (automaticFire == true)
                {
                    anim.Play("SHOOTING");
                    LaunchProjectile();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void LaunchProjectile()
    {
        foreach (var firePoint in firePoints)
        {
            Rigidbody projectileInstance = Instantiate(
                projectilePrefab,
                firePoint.position,
                firePoint.rotation);

            projectileInstance.AddForce(new Vector3(0, 0, 1) * launchForce);

            projectileInstance.gameObject.AddComponent<BulletDestruction>().Init();
        }
    }

    bool isAnimationStatePlaying(Animator anim, int animLayer, string stateName)
    {
        if (anim.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(animLayer).IsName(stateName))
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
}
```

I added the isAnimationStatePlaying method and using it in the Update and it's working very good now.